# How can I change AsyncTask (deperecated) to Coroutines in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines

I am migrating code from AsyncTask to Coroutines because AsyncTask is deprecated. How can I implement the change from AsyncTask to Coroutines in the BookRepository.kt. How can I restructure the code?

```
package com.room.ps.bookkeeper

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.room.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class BookRepository(application: Application) {

    val allBooks: LiveData<List<Book>>
    private val bookDao: BookDao


    init {
        val bookDb = BookRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        bookDao = bookDb!!.bookDao()
        allBooks = bookDao.allBooks
    }

    fun getBooksByBookOrAuthor(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<Book>>? {
        return bookDao.getBooksByBookOrAuthor(searchQuery)
    }


    suspend fun insert(book: Book) {
        InsertAsyncTask(bookDao).execute(book)

    }

    suspend fun update(book: Book) {
        UpdateAsyncTask(bookDao).execute(book)
    }

    suspend fun delete(book: Book) {
        DeleteAsyncTask(bookDao).execute(book)
    }

    companion object {
        private class InsertAsyncTask(private val bookDao: BookDao) : AsyncTask<Book, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg books: Book): Void? {
                bookDao.insert(books[0])
                return null
            }
        }

        private class UpdateAsyncTask(private val bookDao: BookDao) : AsyncTask<Book, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg books: Book): Void? {
                bookDao.update(books[0])
                return null
            }
        }

        private class DeleteAsyncTask(private val bookDao: BookDao) : AsyncTask<Book, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg books: Book): Void? {
                bookDao.delete(books[0])
                return null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html and this https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines ? What you want to do is fairly simple, but it feels like you're not familiar with the basics, and that could give you some trouble - especially when it comes to making sure you're doing the right thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Dao operations are `suspend` you can just call them:

```
suspend fun insert(book: Book) {
    bookDao.insert(book)
}

// the same for other methods
```

If Dao operations are not `suspend` you need to switch coroutine's context to background thread using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` function:

```
private suspend insertBook(book: Book) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    bookDao.insert(book)
}

suspend fun insert(book: Book) {
    insertBook(book)
}

// the same for other methods
```

Comment: Are the AsyncTasks in the companion object to be removed? Yes, I am a novice.

Comment: Yes, they can be removed.